# Insert character to a number datatype column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, type-conversion

**Note: I cant change the datatype of column**

I want to store a character into a table that has column with number datatype.

The work around i found is convert the character values to ASCII and when retrieving it from the database convert it back to character.

I used couple of function ASCII and ASCIISTR but the limitation with these functions are they are converting only first character of the string.

So i used dump function

```
select dump('Puneet_kushwah1') from dual;
```

Result: Typ=96 Len=15: 80,117,110,101,101,116,95,107,117,115,104,119,97,104,49

This function is giving ASCII value of all the characters. Then i execute below query

```
select replace(substr((DUMP('Puneet_kushwah1')),(instr(DUMP('Puneet_kushwah1'),':')+2 )),',',' ') from dual;
```

Result: 80 117 110 101 101 116 95 107 117 115 104 119 97 104 49

then i used a special character to fill the space, so that i can replace it while retrieving from the database.

```
select replace(substr((DUMP('Puneet_kushwah1')),(instr(DUMP('Puneet_kushwah1'),':')+2 )),',','040') from dual;

Result: 80040117040110040101040101040116040950401070401170401150401040401190409704010404049
```

Table definition:

```
create table test (no number);
```

Then i inserted it into the table

```
INSERT into test SELECT replace(substr((DUMP('Puneet_kushwah1')),(instr(DUMP('Puneet_kushwah1'),':')+2 )),',','040') from dual;
```

**Problem 1**:
When i execute

```
select * from test;
```

i got

Result: 8.004011704011E82

I want to convert it into number only. Exact same what i inserted.

**Problem 2:**

And then when i execute select i want it to return the exact character string.

Please help i tried many functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to do seems quite perverse.  Just declare the column to be the appropriate type for the data.

Comment: What's the point of converting into a number?

Comment: You are in trouble if your character could contain a left paren which is decimal 40.

Comment: i would love to know a real world scenario where this would be something that is actually required

Comment: @davegreen100 There is an application which create a table dynamically and one of the column is number, and other data is of spatial type and it generates a report that is input of another tool, so i cant change the datatype of column

Comment: so you're trying to represent any string as a number?  if you can't change the column type, why not add a new column (varchar2).  I guess I'm confused by why you'd need to go this route

Comment: How long might the input string be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I advise not to proceed like this as this could be rife for errors and a possible maintenance nightmare, I do like a challenge and have been forced to do some screwy things myself in order make some vendor's bizarre way of doing things work for us so I sympathize with you if that is the case.  So, for the fun of it check this out.

Convert to hex, then to a decimal and insert into the database (x_test has one NUMBER column), then select, converting back:

```
SQL> insert into x_test
  2  select to_number(rawtohex('Puneet_kushwah1'), rpad('X', length(rawtohex('Puneet_kushwah1')), 'X')) from dual;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from x_test;

      col1
----------
4.1777E+35

SQL> SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(hextoraw(trim(to_char(col1, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'))))
  2  FROM x_test;

UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HEXTORAW(TRIM(TO_CHAR(col1,'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Puneet_kushwah1

SQL>
```

Comment: @Gray_W thanks for your valuable time and efforts, i really appreciate that... i have only one doubt why you are using rawtohex and hextoraw..

Answer (score 5):

You can't get the exact string back because Oracle numbers are only stored up to 38 digits of precision.

So if you run this:

```
select cast(no as varchar2(100))
from test;
```

You'll get:

```
80040117040110040101040101040116040950400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

While it's a horrible idea and a horrible data model, you *could* convert some strings into numbers by converting their raw representation into a number:

```
create or replace function string_to_number(p_string varchar2)
return number as
  l_raw raw(40);
  l_number number;
begin
  l_raw := utl_i18n.string_to_raw(data => p_string, dst_charset => 'AL32UTF8');
  l_number := to_number(rawtohex(l_raw), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  return l_number;
end;
/
```

And back again:

```
create or replace function number_to_string(p_number number)
return varchar2 as
  l_raw raw(40);
  l_string varchar2(20);
begin
  l_raw := hextoraw(to_char(p_number, 'fmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
  l_string := utl_i18n.raw_to_char(data => l_raw, src_charset => 'AL32UTF8');
  return l_string;
end;
/
```

Which you could use as:

```
insert into test (no) values (string_to_number('Puneet_kushwah1'));

1 row inserted.

select * from test;

                                     NO
---------------------------------------
   417765537084927079232028220523112497

select number_to_string(no) from test;

NUMBER_TO_STRING(NO)                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Puneet_kushwah1
```

You don't really need functions, you could do the conversions in-line; but this makes what's happening a bit clearer.

But you're restricted by the precision of the number type. I think you're limited to about 20 characters, but it'll depend a bit on the actual string and its hex representation.

(I am not endorsing this approach, it's just a mildly interesting problem).